# mms-sms/conversations return invalid count in Htc explorer

Tags: android, mms

The code run absolutely fine in other device like samsung ace, sony ericson x10 but in HTC explorer the conversation count return wrong count. Thanks for your concern and my code is as mention below :-

```
final String[] projection = new String[] { "*" };
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations/"); // ?simple=true
            Cursor cursorCoversation = mContext.getContentResolver().query(uri,
                    projection, null, null, null);
cursorCoversation.getCount()
```